# rolling pearson correlation between 2 different length of pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

how can I calculate the rolling pearson correlation between 2 pandas columns please?

As shown in below, I have column A and column B, and I want to get column result.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({             
   'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],                                                      
   'B' : [2,4,6,8,6,4,2,1,4],                                                               
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['corr'] = df.index.map(lambda x: df['A'].corr(df.loc[:x, 'B']))
print(df)

   A  B      corr
0  1  2       NaN
1  2  4  1.000000
2  3  6  1.000000
3  4  8  1.000000
4  5  6  0.832050
5  6  4  0.458682
6  7  2  0.000000
7  8  1 -0.301687
8  9  4 -0.262461
```

Comment: what if I have A as one dataframe and B as another dataframe, and they don't have same length (size)?

Comment: What rolling comparison are you making if they're unequal lengths. In your image, there is no `integer` for `Column B index 3`. I don't understand how you can get this export.

Comment: basically, i want to search in column A, which part looks similar to column B, thats why i deliberately leave blank from index 3.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What constitutes _similar_? Is it within a certain threshold?

Comment: this is why I need to run correlation, it tells me the similarity, no threshold is needed. so basically, i compare A[0:2] to B[0:2], then A[1:3] to B[0:2], A[2:4] to B[0:2] and so on until the end.